# Broken packages held when installing rosdep

Tags: dependencies, ros, lidar

-I am running the following command to visualize the Velodyne Lidar VLP16 output:
`rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne`
-Unfortunately, it keeps telling me to install **rosbash** and running the following command:
`sudo apt install rosbash`
-I keep getting this error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
rosbash : Depends: catkin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

What could be the solution?

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the rosbash package and then ran the `rosdep check --from-paths src --ignore-src` and `sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y` to fix the pacakage dependencies but it did not work.

Comment: What version of ROS are you running? If it's ROS1 you installed ROS incorrectly.